# 環境変数を利用してデータベース接続の管理をしたいのですが上手く読み込まれません

Tags: php, mysql, heroku

**実現したいこと**
環境変数を利用してデータベースの接続を管理したい

**行ったこと**
phpdotenvをインストール

.envファイルの作成(接続内容記入済み)

各接続名の確認

gitignoreにenvファイルを記載

エラー内容がこちらになります。
原文

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException: Unable to read any of the environment file(s) at [/app/.env]. in /app/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Store/FileStore.php:68 Stack trace: #0 /app/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php(222): Dotenv\Store\FileStore->read() #1 /app/connect.php(7): Dotenv\Dotenv->load() #2 /app/index.php(9): connect() #3 {main} thrown in /app/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Store/FileStore.php on line 68
```

翻訳

```
致命的なエラー：キャッチされていないDotenv \ Exception \ InvalidPathException：[/ app/.env]にある環境ファイルを読み取ることができません。 /app/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Store/FileStore.php:68スタックトレース：＃0 /app/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php(222）：Dotenv \ Store \ FileStore-> read （）＃1 /app/connect.php(7）：Dotenv \ Dotenv-> load（）＃2 /app/index.php(9）：connect（）＃3{main}が/ app / vendor / vlucasにスローされます /phpdotenv/src/Store/FileStore.php（68行目）
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記のコード

```php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
function connect()
{
    try {
        $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
        $dotenv->load();

        $dbHost = $_ENV['DB_HOST'];
        $dbUsername = $_ENV['DB_USERNAME'];
        $dbPassword = $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'];
        $dbDatabase = $_ENV['DB_DATABASE'];

        $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$dbDatabase}, host={$dbHost}, charset=utf8, {$dbUsername}, {$dbPassword}");
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    } catch (PDOException $Exception) {
        die('DB接続エラー: ' . $Exception->getMessage());
    }
    return $db;
}
```

調べても中々答えを考えられずどうしたらよいのか分からずにいます。
何かヒントや気付きでもよいのでご回答いただけないでしょうか。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

2021/02/02　追記
.envファイルの内容です。
下記に記入した項目は、heroku configで表示させたデータベース情報を元にしました。

```
DB_HOST="ホスト名"
DB_USERNAME="ユーザー名"
DB_PASSWORD="パスワード名"
DB_DATABASE="データベース名"
```

エラー発生後、.envファイルを確認した際データベース名が間違えていたので修正したのですが解決できませんでした。

追記
heroku側での設定です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: envファイルが読み取れないというエラーのようですが、具体的にどのようにファイルを作成しましたか？

Comment: 追記のように記入いたしました！

Comment: 質問のしかたが良くなかったです。申し訳ないです。ファイルの中身でなく.envファイルをどうやってherokuサーバー上に置きましたか？

Comment: いえ、理解不足で申し訳ありません。herokuサーバー上への置き方がわかりませんでしたので確認しておりました。Config varsに、何も設定していませんでしたので、上記のような形で設定しました。一番上のURLの項目はデフォルトで記入されていたためそのままにしおります。また、的外れな解答でしたらご遠慮無く指摘いただけますとありがたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dotenvの使い方としては、例えばローカル環境のDB接続用のデータを入れておいて、本番サーバなどではホスティングの環境変数（HerokuでいうところのConfig Vars）を利用することで上書きするというやり方が一般的です。
dotenvの環境変数とホスティングの環境変数両方あった場合ではホスティングの環境変数が優先して利用される仕組みです。

そのためローカル環境の接続情報でしたらdotenvファイル自体はignoreせずにgitにプッシュしてしまって運用しても問題ないと思います。

またローカル環境が必要ない & アプリを動作環境に環境変数が設定できるのであれば、そもそもdotenvを利用する必要はないでしょう。
Herokuであれば

```
getenv('XXXXX')
```

で取得できるでしょう。

参考: [環境設定を定義する](https://devcenter.heroku.com/ja/articles/getting-started-with-php#-11)

Comment: ご丁寧に説明いただきありがとうございます。理解が深まりました。エラー内容についての原因なのですが、何か推測出来ることはありますでしょうか。

Comment: エラー自体は.envファイルがないもしくは読み込めないエラーです。そもそもignoreに追加しているのであればファイルはアップロードできていないのでしょう。

Comment: 上記の流れを行った後、Git Hubへ公開をする形で考えていましてその際に注意するべき点などはありますでしょうか。

Comment: 注意するべき点についてですが、質問の内容としてはあいまいな印象です。目的や公開するアプリによってやるべきことは変わってきますし、おそらくこのコメントでやり取りするには不十分でしょう。

Comment: かしこまりました！教えて頂いた方法で一旦試してまた不明点があれば質問します。ご回答ありがとうございます！